# How do i prevent pane intersection blocking another pane? javafx

Tags: java, javafx, interaction, pane

So as in the example code i have two panes (for now A and B) where A pane is above B my problem is that if A pane's bounds are intersecting with B pane's bounds A pane is blocking B pane preventing me to interact with it's children i hope my example code can explain it better what i want.

So what i want to achive is to be able to interact with `Rectangle globalPaneR` with the current bounds of the panes.

```java
package stackoverflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StcakOverFlow extends Application
{
    public static final Pane uiPane = new Pane();
    public static final Pane global_pane = new Pane();
    private Pane localPane = new Pane(global_pane, uiPane);

    @Override
    public void init()
    {
        Rectangle leftTopR = new Rectangle(25, 25, 50, 50);
        Rectangle rightBottomR = new Rectangle(700, 700, 50, 50);
        Rectangle globalPaneR = new Rectangle(600, 600, 50, 50);
        leftTopR.setFill(Color.RED);
        rightBottomR.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
        globalPaneR.setFill(Color.BLUE);

        globalPaneR.setOnMouseClicked(e -> globalPaneR.setFill(Color.LIME));

        uiPane.getChildren().addAll(leftTopR, rightBottomR);
        global_pane.getChildren().add(globalPaneR);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(localPane);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("StackOverFlow");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try that!

Comment: Would `Group` be more suitable over `Pane`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already noticed the `uiPane` is placed on top of the `global_pane` and therefore consuming the all mouse events that should reach the `globalPaneR` rectangle. In this example this can be overcome in several ways:

**Option 1 (most universal)**: Set `pickOnBounds` property value of your 'blocking' pane to `false`.

```
uiPane.setPickOnBounds(false);
```

Documentation says about the [pickOnBoundsProperty](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty):

> Defines how the picking computation is done for this node when triggered by a MouseEvent or a contains function call. If pickOnBounds is true, then picking is computed by intersecting with the bounds of this node, else picking is computed by intersecting with the geometric shape of this node. The default value of this property is false unless overridden by a subclass. The default value is true for Region.

So in this case this basically means that the `uiPane` should not consume mouse events unless the mouse is hovering over it's children (rectangles).

**Option 2**: Use `Group` instead of `Pane` for your nodes which contain the rectangles.

```
public static final Group uiPane = new Group();
```

This works because `Group` doesn't inherit from `Region` (as `Pane` does) and therefore `pickOnBounds` property already has the default value `false`.

**Option 3**: Change the order of your panes.

Obviously this isn't always possible as you may want to listen to mouse events in both panes and may want the children of `uiPane` stay on top of `global_pane`. But in this simple example it would work to just reorder them like this:

```
private Pane localPane = new Pane(uiPane, global_pane);
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answear i will definitely start to use groups instead of panes.